# ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header

Tags: arduino-uno

Hi somebody who can link an beginners guide for ESP 8266 on arduino uno? Or help me with this error :

> Arduino:1.8.9 (Windows 10), Kort:"Generic ESP8266 Module, 80 MHz,
>   Flash, Legacy (new can return nullptr), All SSL ciphers (most
>   compatible), dtr (aka nodemcu), 26 MHz, 40MHz, DOUT (compatible), 4MB
>   (FS:3MB OTA:~512KB), 2, nonos-sdk 2.2.1+100 (190703), v2 Lower Memory,
>   Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"
>
> Executable segment sizes:
>
> IROM   : 227372          - code in flash         (default or
>   ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR)
>
> IRAM   : 26368   / 32768 - code in IRAM          (ICACHE_RAM_ATTR,
>   ISRs...)
>
> DATA   : 1252  )         - initialized variables (global, static) in
>   RAM/HEAP
>
> RODATA : 672   ) / 81920 - constants             (global, static) in
>   RAM/HEAP
>
> BSS    : 24848 )         - zeroed variables      (global, static) in
>   RAM/HEAP
>
> Sketch uses 255664 bytes (24%) of program storage space. Maximum is
>   1044464 bytes. Global variables use 26772 bytes (32%) of dynamic
>   memory, leaving 55148 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920
>   bytes. esptool.py v2.8 Serial port COM3
>   Connecting........_____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____.....____Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Elev\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.6.3/tools/upload.py",
>   line 65, in 
>       esptool.main(cmdline)   File "C:/Users/Elev/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.6.3/tools/esptool\esptool.py",
>   line 2890, in main
>       esp.connect(args.before)   File "C:/Users/Elev/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.6.3/tools/esptool\esptool.py",
>   line 483, in connect
>       raise FatalError('Failed to connect to %s: %s' % (self.CHIP_NAME, last_error)) esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed
>   out waiting for packet header esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to
>   ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header

_

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Comment: is the esp8266 in flashing mode?

Comment: 1. (In the Arduino IDE) Tools > Board > Boards Manager
 2. Scroll down until you see the ESP8266 entry. Click on it.
 3. Click "Install".
 4. Wait for installation to finish.
 5. Click "Close"

Answer (score 0):

If still. facing the issue try these settings

To Program Using Arduino Nano
Pin setup in nano:
Connect Nano GND pin to RST pin (ground to reset)
Pin setup in ESP-01
Connect GND to GPIO-0 (Initiates programming mode)
Connect VCC to CH_PD/CH_EN (Power pin to Chip Enable)
Pin setup between nano and ESP-01
Nano to ESP-01
Connect the VCC to VCC and CH_PD/CH_EN
Connect GND to GND and GPIO-0
Connect Tx to Tx
Connect Rx to Rx